# Have the words in this suggested edit really been changed?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, markdown

In [this suggested edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37966) the "rendered output" tab shows two words changed: "Can" and "mysterious", but in the "markdown" tab shows the addition of only a `<br>` tag.

> [image] [image]
>
> <sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

So how did the "rendered output" think those words were changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<br>` is adjacent to the word 'Can', and since it can't really display a difference of a whitespace.

For 'mysterious', it's vice versa; I think the author of the edit put an <kbd>Enter</kbd> before that word (that's why it starts on a new line in the markdown diff).

Comment: huh, didn't notice the newline in MD, I though it was word wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to see anything, highlighting needs to highlight glyphs. The "Can" is now preceded by `<br>` and "mysterious" has a line break next to it.

There's no good way to highlight line breaks otherwise as they don't really have any width. It's a little easier to see in the markdown view where you can see the `<br>` but even there you have to infer the presence of the line break next to "mysterious".